# Check the current row php

Tags: php, html, mysql

So this is how my table looks like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <table class="agenda">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
               </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   
                   <?php // SELECT ident,COUNT(*) FROM sales GROUP BY ident 
                   
                   foreach($link->query('SELECT ident,COUNT(*) FROM sales GROUP BY ident ASC') as $row) {
                       echo "<tr>";
                       echo "<td>img here</td>";
                       
                       $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ident='{$row['ident']}'";
                       $resultt = $link->query($sql);
                       if ($resultt->num_rows > 0) {
                           while($roww = $resultt->fetch_assoc()) {
                               
                               echo "<td>" . $roww['fullname'] . "</td>";
                           }
                       }
                       echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(*)'] . "</td>";
                       echo "</tr>";
                   }
                   ?>
               </tbody>
           </table>
       </div>
   </div>
```

I am going to limit the query rows to 3 rows only, to display first, second and third place. On the `foreach($link->query('SELECT ident,COUNT(*) FROM sales GROUP BY ident ASC') as $row) {`. How can I do a check like `if $row == 1`, `if $row == 2` or `if $row == 3`?

Comment: Add a counter and increase it on each iteration. Also `LIMIT 3` will reduce amount of receiced data.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: Why do you have `foreach` in one place and `while` in the other. Why don't you stick to using `foreach` always?

Comment: What is the problem with `SELECT ident,COUNT(*) FROM sales GROUP BY ident ASC LIMIT 3` or add a counter just below the foreach loop ? You will get more performance by using `LIMIT` instead of counter variables

Comment: @Dharman Insted of copy/pasting that message about SQLi, why don't mention where I am open to SQLi?

Comment: Here `ident='{$row['ident']}'`

Comment: @Dharman I don't think they are actually vulnerable there, that value is pulled directly from the database with no way for the user to interact. Although, it depends how `indent` is submitted into the database in the first place.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I have just commented as for testing purpose to give some advice to OP.

Comment: @AbhishekKamal Yes I pinged the wrong person, my bad. It's been a long morning already ;)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Where the value comes from doesn't matter. You can't inject PHP variables into SQL string like this. You should always parameterize.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton  Ok no problem ;) , most of the developers first learn PHP or any backed language then they move to **security techniques**.

Comment: @AbhishekKamal I know haha

Comment: @Dharman I agree that you should always parameterize, regardless of actual risk, but I'm just saying that I don't think they are necessarily vulnerable to normal injection in this case.

Answer (score 1):

in your sql you can use LIMIT keyword like below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ident='{$row['ident']}' LIMIT 3";
```